# How to return the position of an odd number in a function?

Tags: python, enumerate

Every time I try to run this code it just keeps returning `None`. It is my first time trying to implement `enumerate()` and have no clue how it functions. I have google videos on it but they don't really go in-depth as to how it really works.

```
def return_position_of_odd(tup: tuple) -> int:
    seen={}

    for i, num in enumerate(tup):
        if num in seen:
            return i%2!=1


print(return_position_of_odd((5, 7, 9, 12, 44, 66)))
print(return_position_of_odd((50, 7, 9, 12, 44, 66)))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `enumerate`. Your function only returns a value if the `if num in seen` condition is `True`. In all other cases, it *implicitly* returns `None` because that's what happens in python with functions that don't explicitly return anything.

Since you initialize `seen` to an empty dict, and never add anything to it, this condition is *always* `False`, so your function always returns `None`.

To fix this, change the condition:

```
def return_position_of_odd(tup: tuple) -> int:
    for i, num in enumerate(tup):
        if num % 2: # You don't need to check if this == 1, since non-zero ints are considered true in python
            return i
```

---

If you want to return the positions of *all* odd numbers, you can use a *list* to keep track of the indices and append to this list whenever you encounter an odd number. Then return the list at the end of your function. Note that your type-hint will change from `-> int` to `-> list[int]` if this is the case. I would also rename the function to `return_positions_of_odd` to more accurately describe what it does

```
def return_positions_of_odd(tup: tuple) -> list[int]:
    ret = []
    for i, num in enumerate(tup):
        if num % 2: 
            ret.append(i)
    return ret
```

Similar to @Daniel's answer, you can condense this function down to a list comprehension, since the only thing the loop does is build the list:

```
def return_positions_of_odd(tup: tuple) -> list[int]:
    return [i for i, num in enumerate(tup) if num % 2]
```

Comment: It seems like the OP maybe wants to return a collection of indices for all odd numbers, rather than just the index of the first odd number.

Comment: @PaulM. I disagree, because their function is type-hinted to return `int` (although that could be because they don't understand that feature of python yet). I've added an alternative nonetheless

Comment: I understand that the enumerate function returns all the odd numbers, but do you know if it can only return the first odd number it finds

Comment: @mugengyutaro If you just  want the first value, use a simple loop and return out of it when your condition is fulfilled, which is what I demonstrated in the first part of my answer. The `enumerate` function __doesn't__ _"return all odd numbers"_ -- it simply yields an index and the item when you iterate over the `enumerate(tup)` instead of simply giving the value when you iterate over `tup`. What you do with this loop is what decides how many indices are returned -- in the first case, you return immediately after you find one odd number. In the second, you find all odd numbers and then return

Comment: Thank you! This actually helps my understanding of enumerate a lot. I didn't know you could just throw an empty dictionary to get multiple and remove the dictionary to get 1 result.

Comment: @mugengyutaro I might be misunderstanding your comment, but you _can't_ just "throw in an empty dictionary". The behavior of the loop is different in either case: In the first case, you return the first value you find. In the second, you collect all these values in a list and then return it. Note that this is a _list_, not a _dictionary_. Where and what you `return` is the deciding factor. For example, I could have done `return ret[0]` instead of `return ret` in my second function and still returned only the first odd number, but that would be a waste of computations to find the other odd nums

Comment: Thank you for explaining this I had absolutely no clue, I can come back to this for reference points in the future this helps me out a tons

Answer (score 2):

Just another reference solution for the same problem, using List Comprehension this time.

```
def return_positions_of_odd(nums: List[int]) -> list[int]:
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(nums) if x & 1]    # x & 1 to get odd
```

Running it:

```
>>> return_positions_of_odd([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 13])
[0, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I wonder if there's any significant speed difference between the bitwise `&` and the modulo operations.

Comment: Prob. not for this *small* list.  but it'll be some *gains* for huge list (>millions) I think.  (need to timing it...)

Comment: How would you make it so it only shows the first odd number?

Comment: I understand the enumerate() functions a little bit more now, but do you know if there is a way to only have it output the first odd number that it finds instead of all?

Comment: Did earlier post has answered the question?

Comment: @DanielHao it would seem that modulo is slightly better than bitwise and for large inputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZfWr.png

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah, last time I checked, `%` still had a fast path while `&` did not.

Comment: Well, my test runs got different results for >2M items. *bitwise* is little better though...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Hmm, I see one in [mod](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cfafd3adf8c3bb73881081f721e77ebfc94431ea/Objects/longobject.c#L3930) but also something in [and](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cfafd3adf8c3bb73881081f721e77ebfc94431ea/Objects/longobject.c#L5072). So... meh... I guess maybe their general being different doesn't really allow obvious predictions...